# How do I crawl the span value only where < strong > is 'Latitude'? NodeJS Cheerio

Tags: javascript, list, scrape, cheerio

Suppose this HTML list:

```
<li>
<strong> Admin name </strong>
<span itemprop="addresslocality"> Amsterdam </span>
<li>
 <li>
<strong> Latitude </strong>
<span itemprop="addresslocality">  52.370216 </span>
<li>
 <li>
<strong> Longitude </strong>
<span itemprop="addresslocality">  4.895168 </span>
<li>
```

How do I get the span value of Latitude and Longitude? If I just .get() the second and third itemprop it gets me unwanted values sometimes. (based on number of itemprop attributes in a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `contains` selector:

```
dom.find('strong:contains("Latitude")').next().text().trim() // 52.370216
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, do you mind to have a quick check on my code to see why something is not working out?

Comment: @user3660293 it probably doesn't work as this is jquery and you haven't said you are using jquery.  Not sure why you accepted an answer when it doesn't work